# How to filter out empty values from Object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object and i want to only get the values that is not an empty string.

`const obj = { a: "", b: "b" }`

How can i filter out b from this object?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck?

Comment: Do you want only the values, as an array? `Object.values(obj).filter(v=>v!=='')`. Or do you want an object that has only properties the value of which are not `""`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = { a: "", b: "b" }

console.log(Object.values(obj).filter(v=>v!==''))
```